# BASH use of variable to check active connectecion

Tags: linux, string, bash, variables, debian

So I have this script (nettest.sh) with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Internet Check

linktest="$(ping -c 1 google.com)"
if [[ $linktest != *"not"* ]]; then
  echo -e " PASSED "
  echo -e " $linktest "
else
  echo -e " FAILED "
  echo -e " $linktest "
fi
```

The result of the ping in case it fails is as follows:

```
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

But this is not working. When I have a link, It shows the right message. But when the link is down, it keeps showing the PASSED message and shows the failed ping message.

Any ideas ?
(Using Debian/Kali)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your attempt doesn't work is because `ping` writes to `stderr` when it fails,
which is not captured by the `$(...)`,
and so `linktest` is empty.

You could make it capture `stderr` if you change the line to this:

```
linktest=$(ping -c 1 google.com 2>&1)
```

But actually, instead of parsing the output,
it would be better to work with the exit code of `ping` directly,
for example:

```
if ping -c 1 google.com; then
  echo " PASSED "
else
  echo " FAILED "
fi
```

You might also want to suppress all output from `ping` completely:

```
if ping -c 1 google.com &>/dev/null; then
```

Comment: Thank you janos, that helped me alot understanding some things in my script. It is working 100%.